# Cv2 findChessboardCorners fails to find corners on the images

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d, calibration, python

I am trying to calibrate the camera with 10-50mm focal lenght, all the images of the chess board are taken with cube size as 0.25cm. when i run the findchessboard function of cv2, it fails to detect the chessboard.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W7xF.png)

```
file = "filename"
img = cv2.imread(file)

# Color-segmentation to get binary mask
lwr = np.array([0, 0, 90])
upr = np.array([179, 61, 252])
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)

plt.imshow(msk)
plt.show()

# Extract chess-board
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50, 30))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)

# Displaying chess-board features
res = np.uint8(res)
plt.imshow(res)
plt.show()

ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9, 7),
                                         flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH +
                                               cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK +
                                               cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE +
                                               cv2.CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE)
if ret:
    print(corners)
    fnl = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7, 7), corners, ret)
    plt.imshow(fnl)
    plt.show
else:
    print("No Checkerboard Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

By simplifying and removing unnecessary parts of your code, you can check that everything works correctly at the OpenCV side.

The number of chessboard corners must be the correct one, (10,7) in this case.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file = "9W7xF.png"
img = cv2.imread(file)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (10, 7),
                                         flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH +
                                               cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK +
                                               cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE +
                                               cv2.CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE)
if ret:
    print(corners)
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (10, 7), corners, ret)
    cv2.imshow("Chessboard features", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
else:
    print("No Checkerboard Found")
```

That outputs the following image:

[image: Chessboard features.]

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

The chessboard detection works fine. Re-check the logic in you code.